# How do you find the shortest path after the BFS algorithm?

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search, shortest

```
while( !q.is_empty() )
{
  loc = q.remove_from_front();

  //cout << loc.row << " " << loc.col << endl;
  if( (loc.row-1) >= 0) //north
  {
     loc2.row = loc.row-1;
     loc2.col = loc.col;

     if(maze[loc2.row][loc2.col] != '#' && visited[loc2.row][loc2.col] == false)
     {
        visited[loc2.row][loc2.col] = true;

        q.add_to_back(loc2);

        //loc = predecessor[loc.row][loc.col];
        predecessor[loc2.row][loc2.col] = loc;

        if(maze[loc2.row][loc2.col] == 'F')
        {
           result = 1;
           maze[loc2.row][loc2.col] = '*';

           break;
        }
     }
  }

  if(loc.col-1 >= 0) //West
  {
     loc2.row = loc.row;
     loc2.col = loc.col-1;

     if(maze[loc2.row][loc2.col] != '#' && visited[loc2.row][loc2.col] == false)
     {
        visited[loc2.row][loc2.col] = true;

        q.add_to_back(loc2);

        //loc = predecessor[loc.row][loc.col];
        predecessor[loc2.row][loc2.col] = loc;

        if(maze[loc2.row][loc2.col] == 'F')
        {
           result = 1;
           maze[loc2.row][loc2.col] = '*';

           break;
        }
     }
  }

  if(loc.row+1 < rows) //South
  {
     loc2.row = loc.row+1;
     loc2.col = loc.col;

     if(maze[loc2.row][loc2.col] != '#' && visited[loc2.row][loc2.col] == false)
     {
        visited[loc2.row][loc2.col] = true;

        q.add_to_back(loc2);

       // loc = predecessor[loc.row][loc.col];
       predecessor[loc2.row][loc2.col] = loc;

        if(maze[loc2.row][loc2.col] == 'F')
        {
           result = 1;
           maze[loc2.row][loc2.col] = '*';

           break;
        }
     }
  }

  if(loc.col+1 < cols) //East
  {
     loc2.row = loc.row;
     loc2.col = loc.col+1;

     if(maze[loc2.row][loc2.col] != '#' && visited[loc2.row][loc2.col] == false)
     {
        visited[loc2.row][loc2.col] = true;

        q.add_to_back(loc2);

        //loc = predecessor[loc.row][loc.col];
        predecessor[loc2.row][loc2.col] = loc;

        if(maze[loc2.row][loc2.col] == 'F')
        {
           result = 1;
           maze[loc.row][loc.col] = '*';

           break;
        }
     }
  }
}

if(result == 1)
{

  while()
  {
      //not sure...
  }
}
```

This is my BFS algorithm and the main reason I asked this question is because the other questions similar to my own question tends to be done with vectors. I haven't learn vectors yet. What I am trying to do is to print the shortest path using '*' characters to display it on valid elements. It should be in bounds, no walls visited (walls are '#' characters), and no element should be visited twice. I know that if I set my predecessor 2D array correctly, the shortest path should be displayed correctly. However, I am not sure if I did set it up correctly and how to actually fill in that path with '*' characters...

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code with the debugger? That's a lot of code you leave us here, with almost no explanation of the context and what it is supposed to do. Try to prepare a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem please.

Comment: If I understood your code right `predecessor` array (or what is it) contains all you need you just need track the path from final vertex of your graph to start